# Are there any new weight initialization techniques for DNN published after 2015?

Tags: deep-learning, reference-request, deep-neural-networks, weights, weights-initialization

Considering weights initialization in my personal projects, I always used some standard techniques such as:

1. Glorot (also known as Xavier) initialization (2010).
2. Mertens initialization (2010).
3. He initialization (2015).

As it is a very active research field, are there some innovations in recent years that have increased the performance of DNNs?

I am thinking specifically of architectures such as DNNs and CNNs with activation functions, such as ReLU,  ELU, PReLU, Leaky ReLU, SELU, Swish, and Mish.

Comment: I found this paper [Improving Weight Initialization of ReLU and Output Layers](http://www.cs.utep.edu/ofuentes/papers/aguirre_fuentes_ICANN_19.pdf) (2019). There's only 1 citation for now (so I don't know how much it's reliable), but, according to their abstract, they obtained good results. You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/aguirrediego/weight-initialization-relu-and-output-layers). Maybe you could have a look at it, and later provide an answer to your own question (if nobody does it).