# Which methods for weight initialization in Neural Networks are currently common practice?

Tags: neural-networks, reference-request, weights, weights-initialization

I am currently researching the topic of weight initialization methods for (deep) neural networks and I'm a little stuck. The result of my work should be an overview of methods that are currently in use.

I already collected information about different methods (Xavier/He, LSUV, Pre-Training, etc.), but I was wondering if anyone has a method that comes to mind (maybe recently developed) that I should look at more closely?

Comment: [Here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/25844/2444) is a related question.